# How to create a new column with the same values of another column based on a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have to current data frame below:

| ID | grade_all | highest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pass | 1 |
| 1 | fail | 0 |
| 1 | fail | 0 |
| 2 | pass | 0 |
| 2 | fail | 1 |
| 3 | fail | 1 |
| 3 | pass | 0 |

and I want this:

| ID | grade_all | highest | final_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pass | 1 | pass |
| 1 | fail | 0 | pass |
| 1 | fail | 0 | pass |
| 2 | pass | 0 | fail |
| 2 | fail | 1 | fail |
| 3 | fail | 1 | fail |
| 3 | pass | 0 | fail |

I want the line that has the 1 to be the one that supersedes and put that value into each of the rows for the same student (same ID).
I thought this would work but its giving me an error

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(ID)%>%
    mutate(final_grade = grade_all[highest ==1]
```

Comment: What about ID 3 shoul final grade not be pass?

Comment: I want it to fail because that's the line with the "1"

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: getting this error
! Problem while computing `final_grade= zoo::na.locf(final_grade)`.
x `final_grade` must be size 1, not 0.

Comment: With your provided dataset it works. I have tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the additional info that you gave I interpret your question as the following:
If `highest == 1` then it should take the value of `grade_all` and apply it to all members in the group for the new column `final_grade`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(final_grade = ifelse(highest == 1, grade_all, NA_character_),
         final_grade = zoo::na.locf(final_grade))
```

```
     ID grade_all highest final_grade
  <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>      
1     1 pass            1 pass       
2     1 fail            0 pass       
3     1 fail            0 pass       
4     2 pass            0 fail       
5     2 fail            1 fail       
6     3 fail            1 fail       
7     3 pass            0 fail
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
> df %>%
+     group_by(ID) %>%
+     mutate(final_grade = grade_all[highest > 0]) %>%
+     ungroup()
# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID grade_all highest final_grade
  <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>
1     1 pass            1 pass
2     1 fail            0 pass
3     1 fail            0 pass
4     2 pass            0 fail
5     2 fail            1 fail
6     3 fail            1 fail
7     3 pass            0 fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, final_grade:=grade_all[which(highest==1)], keyby=.(ID)]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of 1 being interpreted as logical TRUE and vice versa, test if any 'highest' per ID is 1 and index c('fail', 'pass') accordingly:

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(final_grade = c('fail','pass')[any(highest) + 1])
```